# Using an If condition within data.frame

Tags: r, date, if-statement

another tricky question I am unable to solve.

I have two dataframes ("sunshine" and "frost"). One with the cumulative sunshine hours per year and the other one with winter extreme temperatures(Dec-Feb). What I now need to do is, to check these data.frames for Frost.
We talk of Frost in this case, if the temperature goes below -19 degrees. However, if sunshine hours have exceeded 300hs in a year, we talk of Frost at - 21 degrees. However, the other precondition is, that the year in the dataframe Frost has to be checked for the end of the current and the beginning of the following year (Dec. to February). This means, that if sunshine hours exceeded 300hs in 1962, I need to check for Frost in Dec.1962 to Feb 1963.
Here is the data.frames.

```
"Sunshine"

year       hours
1962       396
1963       290
1964       301


"Frost"

Date temperature
1962-12-26 -19.21
1963-01-13 -20.29
1963-01-17 -21.47
1964-01-31 -20.54
```

Now the trouble I am having is on how to combine these to dataframes, so that it shows me only the dates with the Frost temperature, where the condition has been met.

In this case we didnt have  Frost events in Winter 1962 with 19,21° , because sunshine  exceeded 300hrs during the year and the trigger temperature is -21°. In January 1963 we have had a Frost event, because sunshine exceeded 300hs in 1962, so the condition goes up to -21°. Also Frost in 1964, because sunshine exceeded 300 hs in 1963.

```
1963-01-17 -21.47
1964-01-31 -20.54
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this issue.

Comment: what have you tried?  I would merge the two data.frames together on year so you can do row wise logic as a start.  take a look at `?as.Date`, `?strptime` and `merge`.

Answer (score 0):

Taking up Justin's suggestion, and assuming `Frost$Date` has class `Date`:

```
x <- Frost
x$year <- as.numeric(format(x$Date, "%Y"))
x <- merge(x, Sunshine)
x <- transform(x, threshold = ifelse(hours > 300, -21, -19))
subset(x, temperature < threshold)[,2:3]  # Noting that column 1 is year

#         Date temperature
#2 1963-01-13      -20.29
#3 1963-01-17      -21.47
```